# Probabilistic solution Poisson problem

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let us consider the *Poisson problem*

\begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{2}u''=-f\qquad\text{in}\,\,(a,b)\\u(a)=u(b)=0
   \end{cases}

where $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded.
We have obtained two solutions, one analytical, the other probabilistic:

- $u(x)=\int^{a}_bg(x,y)f(y)dy$, where $g$ is the *Green function*
- $u(x) =\mathbb{E}^x[\int^\tau_0 f(B_t)]$ where $\tau=\tau_{(a,b)}$ is the first exit time from $(a,b)$ and $(B_t)_t$ is a *standard Brownian motion*.
  Making equal this two solutions, we obtain, after some passages:
  $$g(x,y)=\int^{\infty}_0\mathbb{P}^x(B_t\in dy,t<\tau)dt$$

Our professor give us the following interpretation.

"Does there exist $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous such that for each level $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have that $$\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{1}_{(f(x)=a)}(x)dx>0?$$

Yes, *Brownian Motion* has this property, infact $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\mathbb{E^x}[\int^{\tau}_0\mathbb{1}_{(f(B_t)=a)dt}]>0$$."

Can someone explain this interpretation, please?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many misprints in the question that it is difficult to know what is really asked. In any case, the identity
$$
g(x,y)=\int^{\infty}_0\mathbb{P}^x(B_t\in dy,t<\tau)\,\mathrm dt
$$
should read
$$
g(x,y)dy=\int^{\infty}_0\mathbb{P}^x(B_t\in dy,t<\tau)\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Later on, the assertion that for all  $a$,
$$\mathbb{E^x}[\int^{\tau}_0\mathbb{1}_{(f(B_t)=a)dt}]>0$$
is just absurd and should probably read
$$\mathbb{E^x}\left[\int^{\tau}_0\mathbb{1}_{B_t=a}\,\mathrm dt\right]>0.
$$
Unfortunately this is wrong as well, since for every $a$,
$$
\int^{\infty}_0\mathbb{1}_{B_t=a}\,\mathrm dt=0,
$$
with full probability. The result your professor is alluding to here might be the existence of a [local time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_time_%28mathematics%29), that is, some family $(L_t^a)$ of random variables such that, for every measurable function $f$, the so-called *occupation formula* holds, that is,
$$
\int^{\tau}_0f(B_t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_\mathbb R f(a)L_\tau^a\,\mathrm da.
$$